# Why won't packages I have installed in the terminal run on Spyder?

Tags: python, spyder

I have been using Jupyter notebook for a while now and it's worked fine. I tried downloading Spyder today and a lot of the packages I installed in the terminal won't work on Spyder.

For example, `pandas_datareader` works fine in Jupyter notebook, but it won't work on Spyder. I get a module not found error when I try to import it.

I tried updating the packages as well as deleting and then reinstalling and it still won't work. I downloaded Spyder from the spyder-ide.org website.

Comment: you may have two Python installed and you could install modules in one Python and Spyder may use other Python. Pythons don't share modules. Run in `Spyder` and `Jupyter` `import sys` `print( sys.executable )` and you will see full path to `Python` used in `Spyder` and `Jupyter` and then you can use `/full/path/to/python -m pip install ...` to install modules in selected Python. You may also check in Spyder's settings if you can set path to Python used in project - this way you may change Python and use different Pythons in different projects (ie. use `virtual environments` in projects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common problem.

You may have two Pythons installed and you use `Jupyter` with one Python but `Spyder` may use other Python.

Different Pythons don't share modules.

Run in `Spyder` and `Jupyter`

```
import sys 

print( sys.executable )
```

to see full path to Python used in `Spyder` and `Jupyter` and then you can use

```
/full/path/to/python -m pip install ...
```

to install modules in correct Pythons.

---

You may also check in Spyder's settings if you can set path to Python used in project - this way you may change Python and use version which has installed modules. This way you can also use different Pythons (with different modules) in different projects (ie. use virtual environments in projects - `venv`)

---

I assumed that `Jupyter` doesn't means [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com) which runs `Jupyter` on Google's server and it install modules on this server - but Spyder runs on local computer.